# Não consigo pegar o parâmetro "id" da URL no Angular 12 usando ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular, typescript, rotas

A URL **'user/1'** por exemplo, não funciona. Mas se utilizo **'/user?id=1'** funciona e consigo listar mas não está no formato que desejo.

No meu construtor declarei um atributo `ActivatedRoute`, o qual utilizo no meu método `ngOnInit()`.

Minha declaração de rotas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: UserComponent}
];
```

Meu `ngOnInit` dentro do `UserComponent`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
      this.userId = params['id'];
      console.log(this.userId);
    });
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza o "subscribe", essa função geralmente só vai ser disparada quando houver alguma mudança de rota.

Para você capturar o parâmetro logo quando o componente inicia, utilize o snapshot.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userId = this.route.snapshot.params["id"]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

É porquê o queryParams é referente à query strings, por isso você consegue pegar quando é `?id=1` para pegar da forma que você quer, você deve utilizar `this.route.params`